# System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories not working after publish

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# application that gets a list of directories inside a folder. This is done using the call 
`String[] projects = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("path/to/folder", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);`

This works fine on my machine, but after publishing (resulting in a setup.exe, as well as programName.application + Application Files) I tried running the program on a new machine and it threw an unhandled exception error.

The error was in regards to being unable to connect to a database, but the interesting part is that it was complaining about **path not being valid**, listing a path that only exists on my machine.

Does System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories not get reinitialized when running on another machine?

Comment: No, that's definitely not your problem. Reformulate your question without that assumption so we can see what's actually going on. Your connectionstring is probably hard-coded to a file on your machine.

Comment: Is "path/to/folder" hard coded? does it exist on the new machine?  What is the actual exception message?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is with `path/to/folder`, as that path might not exist in new machine. Don't hard-code the path. Instead read it from `config` file (`app.config` using `ConfigurationManager`).

Comment: I can't thank you enough, your reply forced me to investigate app.config where I found a connection string that was still around from testing (I switched to the SqlServerCe library shortly after).